# How to sent all members each server a message in 'ready'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When my bot starts up, I want it to send a message to all the members in each server, for example

I want it to say `Hello`.

```js
client.on('ready', message  => {
  client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache.size} servers have members ${client.users.cache.size}`+` | !help `, { type: 'WATCHING' })

  client.guild.send("Hello")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code might be what you need :

```
client.users.cache.forEach(user => {
    try {
        user.send('Hello');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Could not send the message to ${user.tag} : ${e}`);
    };
});
```

This simply grabs all users the bot can communicate with, tries to send a message, and logs an error if the message could not be sent (The error will most likely be caused by the user locking their DMs / blocking the bot).